# java: illegal start of expression for if statement

Tags: java

It keeps saying illegal start of expression by the first if but I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
double total_score = quiz_average * 20% + assignment_average*20% + exam_average * 60%;

if (total_score <= 100 && total_score >= 90) {
    System.out.println("A");
} else if (total_score <= 89.99 && total_score >= 80) {
    System.out.println("B");
} else if (total_score <= 79.99 && total_score >= 70) {
    System.out.println("C");
} else if (total_score <= 69.99 && total_score >= 60) {
    System.out.println("D");
} else if (total_score <= 59.99 && total_score >= 0) {
    System.out.println("F");
}
```

Comment: It keeps saying illegal start of expression by the first if but idk what im doing wrong

Comment: Is your code in a method?

Comment: `60%` is not a valid constant. The `%` is actually the modulo operator. Use `.6` instead and `.2` rather than `60%` and `20%`

Answer (score 1):

In the line:

```
double total_score = quiz_average * 20% + assignment_average*20% + exam_average * 60%;
```

You are using `20%` and `60%`. These are not valid constants. The `%` is actually the modulo operator, ([See under multiplicative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)) which is not what you want. Instead use `.2` and `.6` to get a percentage:

```
double total_sore = (quiz_average * 0.2) + (assignment_average * 0.2) + (exam_average * 0.6);
```